# How To Find Hidden Pictures in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

A long time ago, I remember hiding some really personal files on my computer. Something that nobody could ever find, so I buried them down pretty darn good.

Now to my problem, I don't remember where.

Does anyone know a way to scan a drive and list all hidden folders and/or files?

I know how to view hidden files in Windows, but as far as I know, there is no way to search for them? I've been looking for a program, but I couldn't find one - and now I'm here, asking the experts. ;)

I'd really appreciate any tips.

Comment: Make sure "Display Hidden Files" is enabled in Windows Explorer.  Then go to the top of your Users Folder in Windows, top right Search Bar and search for the files that way. If you hid them in another user id, you would have to log in at that ID and search the same way.

Comment: @John this'll show all results, not only hidden. Not much help.

Comment: Search will show you everything. You must check each user. Then if you put the files elsewhere than Users you will need to search all of C:

Comment: Search your C drive for .jpeg, jpg .png, it will find them.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a powershell command. Something like..

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Hidden -Force -Recurse
```

If you know the type of file you're looking for you can add '-include *.jpg' for example.

Comment: They hid them by burying them on the C drive somewhere (obscure location), not by changing the properties to Hidden.

Comment: "I know how to view hidden files in Windows" is misleading then.  Also, this will still locate the files if they know the file type using -include as stated.

Answer (score 0):

The command [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) will search an entire drive for hidden files & directories

```
dir c:\ /A:H /S /B > biglist.txt
```

and should be run from the Command Prompt of your home directory, i.e., C:\Users*yourusername* so you can easily find that file. When you open the Command Prompt with {**START**} **Windows System** | **Command Prompt** , that's the directory it starts in.

Then, with a good text editor which won't choke on a very large file (I recommend the excellent Open Source [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) , open *biglist.txt* and look for your files.

To narrow it down, you can search for just one file type (e.g., .MP3, .DOC, .DOCX, .PNG, .JPG, .GUF, et al.), which may help.  To look for only RTF files, for example, use

```
dir C:\*.RTF /A:H-D /S /B > RTFlist.txt
```